# Form post action from smarty template

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, smarty

I've the following problem...

My application uses the php, smarty templates and jQuery.

Inside the smarty template there is defined a form with POST method.
The action parameter of the form is defined as follows:

action={if isset($search_place)} {link->somePhpFunction($search_place) {/if}

...because I need to change the action depending on the POSTED parameter.

The input (text) with the "search_place" name is defined inside the form.

The submit button is linked to the jQuery function, as I need to perform some actions on the client side (value check, autocomplete, etc.).

When the button is clicked, I need to
The problem is that when I post the form by the jQuery button, the form will not take the

When the button is clicked then the jQuery handler is called where some checks/corrections are performed and then the page with the form is displayed.

The problem is, that before defining the action parametr from the form the search_place variable in not known and the php function is not called at all. 
I've also tried to set a cookie in the button handler and to set the form action to the {$smarty.cookies.search_place} value but the problem changed into another one - the form allway performes action of the previous button click so it is necessary to click the button TWO TIMES to get the correct results.

It is also necessary to mention that there is no way to transfer the needed action parameter to the jQuery event handler as the php function selects the correct one from the large table in database. If this is possible, then it would be easy to change the action parameter from the jQuery function...

The only way I know is to use AJAX to get the right parametr and assign the correct action parametr from the button event handler but it is not the right solution for me as many of my site visitors have not the browser javascipt enabled.

The solution could be also to perform (programmaticaly) one more click on the button from the jQuery event handler but I don't know how to do it...

Any help or idea how to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated...

Thank you in advance. JaM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<form onsubmit="return validationFunction()">
```

and let this function validate the data and return true if correct and false if not.

now for the js. don't call something like

```
$("#someForm").submit();
```

instead use:

```
if(validationFunction()){
   $("#someForm").submit();
}
```

**Update**

finally if your validationFunction will do some server-side work

Then instead some variable like

var formSubmitted = false;

then onSubmit return false;  and set the formSubmitted to true, and do your ajax call, and when the ajax call is done, check the formSubmitted if it's true then submit the form if not then show some error...

Comment: Hello Shehabix,thank you for your answer but I need it without AJAX. Any other idea?